# Using PBKDF2 encryption in a Metro (WinRT) application

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, windows-runtime, pbkdf2

I need to derive a key from a salted password using PBKDF2 encryption in a C# & C++ Metro (WinRT) application.  What should I use to derive a key using PBKDF2 (like OpenSSL's PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1 call does) on Metro?  Is there a version of OpenSSL that builds on WinRT?  (I've read that it only builds on Windows for the desktop platform.)  Or is there some other solution I should use?

BTW I could call the function from either C# or C++, so either is fine.  Any advice would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I just found a .NET function named "Rfc2898DeriveBytes" -- details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).  If I'm reading that correctly it will do the same thing as OpenSSL's PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1 call -- is that correct?

**EDIT #2:**
Unfortunately it looks like I can't use Rfc2898DeriveBytes after all in my Windows 8.1 Metro app because despite what the [Microsoft documentation for Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) says, that API method does not exist in the 'Windows.Security.Cryptography' namespace when building a Windows 8.1 app.  Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but as there is a bit more to it I've written an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging around I finally found [this link](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=8f9ecac4-80d2-47c8-8c41-9d7877565bf5).  Here is what I ended up doing in my Metro app:

```
private static bool GetPBKDFDerivedKey(string password, 
    byte[] salt,                    // length = 32 bytes (256 bits)
    out byte[] encryptionKeyOut)    // length = 32 bytes (256 bits)
{            
    IBuffer saltBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(salt);
    KeyDerivationParameters kdfParameters = KeyDerivationParameters.BuildForPbkdf2(saltBuffer, 10000);  // 10000 iterations

    // Get a KDF provider for PBKDF2 and hash the source password to a Cryptographic Key using the SHA256 algorithm.
    // The generated key for the SHA256 algorithm is 256 bits (32 bytes) in length.
    KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider kdf = KeyDerivationAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(KeyDerivationAlgorithmNames.Pbkdf2Sha256);
    IBuffer passwordBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(password, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    CryptographicKey passwordSourceKey = kdf.CreateKey(passwordBuffer);

    // Generate key material from the source password, salt, and iteration count
    const int keySize = 256 / 8;  // 256 bits = 32 bytes  
    IBuffer key = CryptographicEngine.DeriveKeyMaterial(passwordSourceKey, kdfParameters, keySize);

    // send the generated key back to the caller
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(key, out encryptionKeyOut);

    return true;  // success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` as the [RFC actually defines PBKDF2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2). Note that you need to make sure you use the same character encoding, salt size and number of rounds to be compatible. Normally SHA1 is used as underlying hash function (which is fine) but beware that PBKDF2 may also use other hash functions. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` utilizes SHA1 for the HMAC functionality.

Note that `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` utilizes UTF-8; this is not documented (even after multiple requests) by Mickeysoft. You can use byte arrays instead if you are unsure about the encoding on both platforms. You should especially be aware of this if you allow characters out of the US ASCII range.

Comment: Thanks for this, especially the UTF-8 info!  I'll use [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) in my app.

Comment: I hit a snag here -- although the Microsoft documentation for Rfc2898DeriveBytes says, "Platforms: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8.1, ...", Visual Studio is failing during compilation with "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Rfc2898DeriveBytes' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.Security.Cryptography'".  Is there anything else I can use??

Comment: I guess you could use the Mono source code for the same class, as it seems to be MIT licensed. You may need to put in a different HMAC implementation though. There should be other code out there that implements it as well. Note that it is not *extremely* hard to implement once you've got the HMAC or even SHA functionality.

Comment: It turns out there is a way to do it in Windows 8, it's just rather obscure (and the Microsoft docs for Rfc2898DeriveBytes being just plain wrong don't help).  I posted another answer with the details.  Thanks for the tip on UTF-8 in any case, it was spot-on.

Comment: Glad you got it solved dbeachy1. I'm in the crypto business too long to think of that as "rather obscure" though :)